# Hazelcast Jet - Support for multiple clients

Tags: hazelcast-jet

Can Hazelcast Jet be used for processing of millions of records using multiple clients accessing an event journal and each client would process a portion of the records?

Furthermore, is it possible to accumulate the results processed by different clients?

Comment: If by "client" you mean a Jet processor running in a Jet cluster, then that's what happens. Jet clients don't process data, they order Jet to process it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Hazelcast Jet Query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49747170/hazelcast-jet-query)

Answer (score 0):

This is also an architectural question. To fit your aggregation need, you might have clients begin as individual streams, accumulate your aggregates there, then join the streams for common processing. Just as an example.

Also, you do have access to the underlying IMDG technology that you can leverage. You have a free hand at how you want to build the overall architecture.